# Can't run OpenAL4Android example in Android Studio

Tags: android, android-ndk, java-native-interface, openal

I am trying to use OpenAL on Android to generate spatial audio and I really struggled to wrap my mind around NDK and JNI and all that stuff.

**Note**: it's the first time i use JNI and NDK and i'm quite new to android development

But I found a library called OpenAL4Android. In addition [here](http://pielot.org/2011/11/openal4android-2/) is an example app that's using it (under "HelloOpenAL4Android" title). The project is old and was done in Eclipse. So what I did was:

- imported the project in Android Studio (New->Import Project)
- created gradle.properties file and added android.useDeprecatedNdk=true; otherwise i get an error. Then Android Studio loaded "OpenAL4Android" as a library to the project(called "helloOpenAL4Android")
- changed the min and target sdk from 7 to 15(min) and 23(target) in build.gradle
- tried to build the project but i get the following error :
  [image]

in openalwrapper.h header at

```
#include <AL/al.h>
#include <AL/alc.h>
```

and i also got this error when i was trying to build from Android Studio OpenAL4Android and OpenAL-MOB in order to integrate them in my projects.

On the other hand i managed to build the .so shared libraries for all ABI's not just armeabi from OpenAL4Android by runing :

> ndk-build.cmd NDK_PROJECT_PATH=D:\AndroidProjects\OpenAL4Android\app\src\main

Do you know why i keep getting this error of AL/al.h not being found? I tried placing that folder(AL/al.h) everywhere, still not found.

Does it have to do with Android Studio not supporting NDK properly? Should i use an experimental gradle plugin?

It's really killing me.

...please help! :)

PS: sorry for the long post, i'm quite desperate i can't complete my project and i'm running out of time.

---

EDIT1:

This is my Android.mk file:

```
TARGET_PLATFORM := android-23
ROOT_PATH := $(call my-dir)


########################################################################################################
include $(CLEAR_VARS)

LOCAL_MODULE     := openal
#LOCAL_ARM_MODE   := arm
LOCAL_PATH       := $(ROOT_PATH)
LOCAL_C_INCLUDES := $(LOCAL_PATH) $(LOCAL_PATH)/../openal/include $(LOCAL_PATH)/../openal/OpenAL32/Include
LOCAL_SRC_FILES  := ../openal/OpenAL32/alAuxEffectSlot.c \
                    ../openal/OpenAL32/alBuffer.c        \
                    ../openal/OpenAL32/alDatabuffer.c    \
                    ../openal/OpenAL32/alEffect.c        \
                    ../openal/OpenAL32/alError.c         \
                    ../openal/OpenAL32/alExtension.c     \
                    ../openal/OpenAL32/alFilter.c        \
                    ../openal/OpenAL32/alListener.c      \
                    ../openal/OpenAL32/alSource.c        \
                    ../openal/OpenAL32/alState.c         \
                    ../openal/OpenAL32/alThunk.c         \
                    ../openal/Alc/ALc.c                  \
                    ../openal/Alc/alcConfig.c            \
                    ../openal/Alc/alcEcho.c              \
                    ../openal/Alc/alcModulator.c         \
                    ../openal/Alc/alcReverb.c            \
                    ../openal/Alc/alcRing.c              \
                    ../openal/Alc/alcThread.c            \
                    ../openal/Alc/ALu.c                  \
                    ../openal/Alc/android.c              \
                    ../openal/Alc/bs2b.c                 \
                    ../openal/Alc/null.c                 \

LOCAL_CFLAGS     := -DAL_BUILD_LIBRARY -DAL_ALEXT_PROTOTYPES
LOCAL_LDLIBS     := -llog -Wl,-s

LOCAL_STATIC_LIBRARIES := libtremolo

include $(BUILD_SHARED_LIBRARY)

########################################################################################################

include $(CLEAR_VARS)

LOCAL_MODULE     := openalwrapper
LOCAL_ARM_MODE   := arm
LOCAL_PATH       := $(ROOT_PATH)
LOCAL_C_INCLUDES := $(LOCAL_PATH)/../openal/include $(LOCAL_PATH)/../openal/tremolo
LOCAL_SRC_FILES  := openalwrapper.c                             \
                    org_pielot_openal_OpenAlBridge.c    \

LOCAL_LDLIBS     := -llog -Wl,-s

LOCAL_STATIC_LIBRARIES := libtremolo
LOCAL_SHARED_LIBRARIES := libopenal

include $(BUILD_SHARED_LIBRARY)

########################################################################################################
```

and the openal forder is at the same level with jni folder
folder structure:

```
OpenAL4Android
    -app
    --src
    ---main
    -----jni
    -----openal
    -----java
    -----jniLibs
    -----res
```

Comment: What does your Android.mk look like?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Nevermind, I got it working. I integrated it in my project. Had to use experimental gradle plugin and then had to run again ndk-build so it generated the libraries in libs folder. First I got some errors saying it can't find the implementation of the native methods because I thought it will get it's libraries from the jniLibs folder.